# I have an instance of JMenuItem (let's say, TEMP). I want to find out, what is the name of JMenu to which a TEMP is added. How?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

I have an instance of JMenuItem (let's say, TEMP). I want to find out, what is the name of JMenu to which a TEMP is added. How should I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to get hold of that information? Don't you know what menu you are adding the item to?

Comment: actually, no. i have a recursive program that adds jmenuitems to jmenus according to not-constant file-system, so my program can never tell what's going on inside of a recursive function... any ideas? :S

Comment: maybe adding every instance of jmenuitem with it's path to jmap will do?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code to get JMenu of given JMenuItem

```
JPopupMenu fromParent = (JPopupMenu)menuitem.getParent();  
JMenu foo = (JMenu)fromParent.getInvoker();  
System.out.println(foo.getName());
```

Comment: JPopupMenu is component where you see all your JMenuItems

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at TextEditor.GetParentOfJMenuItem(Main.java:201)
 at TextEditor.<init>(Main.java:122)
 at Main.main(Main.java:29)
that's what compiler says.

Comment: JMenuItem redoChangesItem = new JMenuItem("ცვლილებების აღდგენა");
  JPopupMenu fromParent = (JPopupMenu)redoChangesItem.getParent();  
  JMenu foo = (JMenu)fromParent.getInvoker();
  System.out.println(foo.getName());

Comment: @Nika: no wonder you get an NPE - the redoChangesItem is not yet added to any menu, so _has no_ parent

Answer (score 0):

You may get the JMenu's name from JMenuItem using this approach:

```
JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.setName("popup");
JMenu jMenu= new JMenu("menu");
jMenu.setName("menu");
JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("sub1");
jMenu.add(menuItem1);
menuItem1.addActionListener(this);
popup.add(jMenu);
```

....

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
    try{
        JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem) e.getSource(); 
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = (JPopupMenu) menuItem.getParent(); 
        Component invoker = popupMenu.getInvoker();  
        // Print name of JMenu
        System.out.println("NAME OF JMENU: "+invoker.getName());    
        JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu) invoker.getParent();
        // Print name of JPopupMenu
        System.out.println("NAME OF POPMENU: "+popup.getName());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```